# Error in the viewer on try proxy a access token

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm trying to make a proxy in the viewer to don't send the access token to the front-end, I implemented my app like this example [link](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/securing-your-forge-viewer-token-behind-proxy-net)

The back-end seems fine but I got a error on the load of the viewer...

```
 viewer3D.js?v=2.17:6698 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'responseText' property from 'XMLHttpRequest': The value is only accessible if the object's 'responseType' is '' or 'text' (was 'json').
        at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/viewer3D.js?v=2.17:6698:59)
```

Different to the sample I'm using Asp.NET MVC 5, have any magic trick to make this work on MVC?

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Would you mind provide a reproducible case which contains a minimum MVC app and a minimum Forge app demonstrating this issue to `forge.help@autodesk.com`? Need to debug. Thanks~ **P.S. please remove confidential data from anything you provided.**

Comment: Any update for the reproducible case?